# Adjust web content according to device location in a wifi area (proximity detection)

Tags: wifi, proximity

I have an open wifi hotspot and a web server and I'm trying to set up a kind of [proximity marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_marketing). Basically I'd like to adjust the content of the web pages sent by my web server providing specific information according to the geographic position of the device that is running the web client.

This should allow a user to connect his device and surf to a static URL and then, when walking around the hotspot area, read special contents each time he walks near some places (i.e. a statue).

As I said, I have full access and can manage both the wifi infrastructure and the web server, but I need to accomplish this using wifi only (i.e. without involving bluetooth, umts or other technologies).
I've heard about [WPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) but I can't understand how that works.
Any pointer or suggestion is really appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: A statue?  For curiosity's sake, would you like to tell us about the place in which you will do proximity marketing?

Comment: This has little to do with marketing, I'm setting it up for a temporary outdoor exhibit and will eventually be rearranged and stay for tourist information purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPS may not be useful, as it only works within 10-20 meters.

Have you considered QR codes? There is a local museum that uses them very effectively for a guided informational tour which may be close to your application. You could serve adds in addition to whatever info you are providing.

You could also rent tablets with QR capability that are preconfigured for your network.  It could possibly generate revenue for your exhibit and might provide you with sponsorship opportunities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want to do is even possible.   Mainly because even if you got a distance estimation you still have 360 dregs of broadcast to deal with.

Someone already mentioned QR codes but you might be able to get buy with simpler barcodes if you have full access to the web server.   The idea being that the barcode supplies a simple text string that your web server can deal with and serve up apage based on that.   I know on some corporate web sites users can access internal web resources by typing a simple word in the address bar.

I'm not sue how complex your location is but the alternative might be to serve up a map/pic that users can tap based on their current location.  The problem here is that a lot of people have no idea where they are.

By the way even though QR codes would work fine for most stackoverlow users I have this feeling that they would suck for the general public.  For example first they would need a smart phone and then they would need a QR code reader and on top of all of that they would need to know how to use the stuff in this context.  I understand a bit what you are trying to do but frankly I think you will only reach a small minority of the population this way.  On top of all of that smart phone users are the least likely in my opinion to open themselves up to marketing.  They already deal with such crap daily, most will actively avoid even more of an intrusion.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use QR codes with your local URLs, so only those devices that are connected to your WiFi Hotspot can get content.
Also try to consider [Google Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby/) and [Physical Web](https://google.github.io/physical-web/) features that is based on beacon devices with [Eddystone-URL](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone) support.